# Not able to pass collection name as a variable to JavaScript from MongoDB command line

Tags: mongodb

I need to pass the collection name as parameter to a Javascript from MongoDB command line.

```
var bulk = db.col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
{
//lines of code
}
```

I am using the below string to connect and run the .js file

```
mongo "mongodb://10.19.129.67:27017,10.19.129.68:27017/dbname?replicaSet=rp-01" --authenticationDatabase=admin --username=usr --password=password'--eval "var col = my_collection" < script.js
```

I am not able to run it, the script just connects to MongoDB and exits.
When I run this by giving the Collection name directly, the script works fine. Please suggest how to pass the collection name from outside the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a comprehensive write up on this:
[Running MongoDB scripts with command line arguments](https://www.moschetti.org/rants/mongoargs.html)

But since just external links are frowned upon, the gist of the approach is this:  use the `--eval` argument along with the script to pass in javascript (not JSON, javascript!) that will be evaluated *before* the script is loaded and run, e.g.:

```
mongo myscript.js --eval 'args={"product":"D"};'

At the "top" of myscript.js, we see this:

if(typeof args !== 'undefined') {
    if(typeof args.product !== 'undefined') { product = args.product; }  // product is now 'D'
}
```

Be careful to distinguish between variables (e.g. strings that name something like `"myCollection"`) and objects (e.g. `db.foo`).  In general, you will want to pass variables in `--eval` and in the script use them to set up objects.  For example, this treatment is incorrect:

```
--eval 'args={"col":"db.my_collection"};' 

(in script:)
if(typeof args !== 'undefined') {
  if(typeof args.col !== 'undefined') {
    col = args.col;  # col is not an object; it is the string "db.my_collection"
  }
}
var bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();  # ERROR! col is not a collection object.
```

This is the proper way.  Note we use `colname` to reinforce the point:

```
--eval 'args={"colname":"my_collection"};' 

(in script:)
if(typeof args !== 'undefined') {
  if(typeof args.colname !== 'undefined') {
    col = db[args.colname];  # ah!  Use string "my_collection" to lookup the col object in db
  }
}
var bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();  # OK!
```

Comment: Getting TypeError col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp() is not a function

Tried the below syntax :
mongo "mongodb://10.19.129.67:27017,10.19.129.68:27017/dbname?replicaSet=rp-01" --authenticationDatabase=admin --username=usr --password=password script.js --eval 'args={"col":"db.my_collection"};'

Changed my script.js to have

if(typeof args !== 'undefined') {
    if(typeof args.col !== 'undefined') { col = args.col; }  
}
var bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
{
//lines of code
}

Comment: You are mixing variables and objects.   You probably have to do something like this: `args={"colname":"myCollectionName"}` and then in the script (I am leaving off the guard wrappers):
`val col = db[colname];
var bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); { //lines of code } `

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me. Please append the code change that you suggested in the comments in your answer so that I can accept the answer. Thanks again.